# What is meant by "orbit" in this question?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

I was reading "Prove that Anosov Automorphisms are chaotic," and the answer and a few of the comments talked about orbits. I'm curious what is meant by "orbits" in the given context. Is it analogous to transformations?

[This is the link.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248914/prove-that-anosov-automorphisms-are-chaotic)

Comment: This is the usual meaning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbits_and_stabilizers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a set $S$, a function $f:S\to S$, and an element $x$ in $S$, the orbit of $x$ is the set $$\{{\,x,f(x),f(f(x)),f(f(f(x))),\dots\,\}}$$