# Why are hyperbolic toral automorphisms (e.g. Arnold's cat map) ergodic?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $\varphi : \mathbb{T}^2 \to \mathbb{T}^2$ be a hyperbolic automorphism of the torus, induced by a linear map $A : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ of determinant $\pm 1$ with no eigenvalues of modulus 1. What is an easy way to prove that $\varphi$ is ergodic?

It's true that the stable and unstable manifolds at $(0,0) \in \mathbb{T}^2$ (projections of the eigenspaces of $A$ to the torus) are dense in the torus, which can be used to prove that such maps are [topologically mixing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixing_%28mathematics%29#Topological_mixing).
An example is [Arnold's cat map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold%27s_cat_map).

Arnold and Avez show in Ergodic Problems in Classical Mechanics that Arnold's cat map is ergodic by proving that it has "Lebesgue spectrum", which implies that it is [strong mixing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixing_%28mathematics%29#Mixing_in_dynamical_systems), which implies that it is ergodic. Is there a more direct way to prove this?

Comment: A few weeks ago, someone here asked for a proof that these maps are chaotic. I found one in a textbook by Elaydi on discrete dynamical systems. The hardest part was proving the map transitive.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I saw [that thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248914/prove-that-anosov-automorphisms-are-chaotic). I found a simpler proof of a stronger statement (topologically mixing) in the [book by Broer and Takens](http://www.math.rug.nl/~broer/pdf/nova.pdf) (proposition 2.15, page 111). But I don't see how topological transitivity or mixing can help me prove that these maps are ergodic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest using the following characterization of ergodicity:

> $\varphi$ is ergodic if and only if every $f\in L^2(\mathbb{T}^2)$ such that $f\circ \varphi = f$ is constant function.

Now let's use this criterion to prove $\varphi$ is ergodic. Suppose $f\in L^2$ with $f\circ \varphi = f$. Decompose $f$ into its Fourier series $$f = \sum_{m,n\in \mathbb{Z}} = \alpha_{(m\,n)}e^{2\pi imx}e^{2\pi iny},$$ with coefficients $\alpha_{(m\,n)}\in \mathbb{C}$. Then, if $\varphi$ is given by the matrix $$A = \left(\begin{matrix} a & b\\c & d\end{matrix}\right),$$ it is easy to compute that $$f\circ \varphi = \sum_{m,n}\alpha_{(m\,n)}e^{2\pi i(ma+nc)x}e^{2\pi i(mb+nd)y}.$$ Since $f$ is invariant, the Fourier series for $f$ and $f\circ \varphi$ must agree, so $\alpha_{(m\,n)} = \alpha_{(ma+nc\,mb+nd)}$ for all $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$. We can express this more simply as follows. If $v = (m\,\,n)\in \mathbb{Z}^2$, then $\alpha_v = \alpha_{vA}$. By iterating, $\alpha_v = \alpha_{vA^k}$ for each $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Suppose that $v\in \mathbb{Z}^2$. Either the sequence $vA^k$ of vectors with integer coordinates is periodic, or else $\|vA^k\|\to \infty$ as $k\to \infty$. Note that the first case cannot happen unless $v = 0$, since if $v = vA^k$ for some $k$, then $A^k$ would have $1$ as an eigenvalue, which contradicts the assumption of hyperbolicity. Thus either $v = 0$, or $\|vA^k\|\to \infty$. Suppose $v\neq 0$. Since  $f\in L^2$, the coefficients $\alpha_{(m\,n)}\to 0$ as $\|(m\,\,n)\|\to \infty$, and thus $\alpha_v = \alpha_{vA^k}\to 0$, i.e., $\alpha_v = 0$. We have therefore shown that the only way $\alpha_v$ can be nonzero is if $v = 0$. The Fourier series for $f$ is then $f = \alpha_0$, so $f$ is a constant function.