# A question on showing $f$ is topological transitive.

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, unimodular-matrices, topological-dynamics

Consider $\mathbb{T}^2=\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ and the following unimodular matrix
\begin{equation}
A=\begin{bmatrix}
2& 1\\
1& 1
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
We know $F\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $F(\mathbf{v})=A\mathbf{v}$ induces a well-defined map $f\colon\mathbb{T}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{T}^2$, $f([\mathbf{v}])=[A\mathbf{v}]$ since $F(\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$. Now I want to show $f$ is **topological transitive**, i.e., for any $U,V\subset \mathbb{T}^2$ open, there exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f^{(n)}(U)\cap V\not=\varnothing$ (since $A^{-1}$ is also unimodular, so $f$ is invertible).

**Here is my attempt:** I try to show $f$ has a dense orbit $\{f^{n}(p)\colon n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ in $\mathbb{T}^2$. If so, then take any $x\in U$, $y\in V$, there exists subsequence $f^{(m_j)}(p)\rightarrow x$, $f^{(n_k)}(p)\rightarrow y$. So there exists $N_1,N_2\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f^{(N_1)}(p)\in U$, $f^{(N_2)}(p)\in V$. Then $p\in f^{(-N_1)}(U)$ and $f^{(N_2-N_1)}(U)\cap V\not=\varnothing$.

**But the question is**, I can't make sure such dense orbit exists. $A$ has two irrational eigenvalues
\begin{equation}
\lambda_1=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2},\,\mathbf{v}_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2}
\end{bmatrix},\,\,\,\lambda_2=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2},\,\mathbf{v}_2=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
\frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2}
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
I guess that $\left\{[\lambda_1^n\mathbf{v}_1]\colon n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$, $\left\{[\lambda_2^n\mathbf{v}_2]\colon n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$ are two dense orbits. We already know $\{[A^nq]\colon n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a periodic orbit for every $q\in\mathbb{Q}^2$. So I am guessing the irrationality of $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ produces density.

Could you provide me with any hints?

Comment: Do you know that this map is ergodic?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262115/why-are-hyperbolic-toral-automorphisms-e-g-arnolds-cat-map-ergodic

Comment: @Moishe Kohan I see the answer! Thank you!